# Create dynamic class-views in pyramid

Tags: python, templates, nested, pyramid, factory

I am trying to reduce my code writing in my Pyramid views and I'm trying to do it via a factory function.

Thus, instead of having something like this in my **views.py**:

```python
class MyView(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name='view', renderer='templates/view.pt')
    def get(self):
        return dict(msg='Hello!')
```

I try having something like this instead:

```python
def factory(cls_name, rtn, rndr, myfun):
    class Cls(object):
        def __init__(self, request):
            self.request = request

        @myfun(route_name=rtn, renderer=rndr)
        def get(self):
            return dict(msg='Hello!')

    Cls.__name__ = cls_name
    return Cls

MyView = factory('MyView', 'view', 'templates/view.pt', view_config)
```

The reason is, obviously, that I'll end up having many classes that could utilise the same class functionality and I want to reduce my code writing. In case you ask me to use inheritance instead, then I'm stuck as to how to configure my derived classes to have a parameterised decorator (like `myfun`). In essence, I need something like a template in C++.

So, even though the above second snippets does not generate any errors, and to me it seems to work just fine, when I try to run it in my test site (by replacing the second snippet with the second one), the routes are not understood by pyramid, so I'm getting a `404 error`. Based on the error, I presume that my problem is probably related with how pyramid parses the **views.py** file to find `view_config` decorators, but I am not sure how to address it.

My **__init__.py**'s main function is somehow like this:

```python
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """      
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_route('view', '/')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thanks all in advance!

Comment: Check out this: https://bitbucket.org/websauna/websauna.viewconfig - I created `@view_overrides` decorator which allows you to subclass the base class only change a part of it. The approach of creating classes dynamically is quite un-Pythonic and makes code hard to follow. Instead, I suggest using static class structure and then modify your classes with decorators and functions if needed.

Comment: But Mikko, this will not solve my problem with parameterised decorators, since I'll still have to override all methods that have decorators, even if I'll only have to call its parent class counterparts. And my initial question is that since the above code is syntactically correct, which part of pyramid's internals isn't it

Comment: And my initial question is that since the above code is syntactically correct and does what I want, what's wrong with it and  pyramid ignores its execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of you code not working is the details of the *scan* process performed by Pyramid on startup to find and process all `@view_config` decorators. For one thing, the `@view_config` docstring says:

```
    ``view_config`` will work ONLY on module top level members
    because of the limitation of ``venusian.Scanner.scan``.
```

So I guess either your classes are created too late in the startup process or something in your dynamically-generated classes confuses venusian. If you have a look at `venusian`'s source code you may be able to find the cause.

However, I'd like to point out that the approach strikes me as a bit recursive... There are ways in Pyramid to register a view without any decorators. Then Pyramid authors added a layer of "syntax sugar" on top of that to simplify the most common use-case and be able to register a view by simply adding a decorator. Then you start fighting those decorators to be able to register a view by what looks like a function call :)

Have a look at [pyramid.config.Configurator.add_view()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_view) - it already looks very much like your "factory function" but you may be able to write a simple wrapper around it if you want.

```
class MyView(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def get(self):
        return dict(msg='Hello!')

config.add_view(MyView, attr='get', route_name='view_cats', renderer='templates/view_cats.pt')
config.add_view(MyView, attr='get', route_name='view_dogs', renderer='templates/view_dogs.pt')
```

Comment: Sergey, my first impression is that I like your suggestion with config.add_view(). The only design-specific "disadvantage" that I see is that this approach sort of couples view creation with configuration (which I know is part of Pyramid's way, but view_config decorators helped in decoupling these two parts). On the other hand, the way I see it, I think it should allow me to do my job, so I'll give it a try to see how it works. Thanks for the suggestion!